# How can I check if any exception has already been thrown?

Tags: c#, exception, dispose

I'm working on some test automation for a service, and figured out a neat way to roll up some common setup & verification into a 'session' class.

Conceptually, a test case might look like this:

```
using (var managerSession = new Session(managerRole))
{
    // A manager puts some items in warehouse
}

using (var employeeSession = new Session(employeeRole))
{
    // An employee moves items from warehouse to store
}

using (var customerSession = new Session(customerRole))
{
    // A customer can buy items from the store
}
```

In the Session object constructor I set up a connection to the service I'm testing with proper authentication per role etc, and in the session Dispose() method I have a common validation block that, for instance, checks that no server-side errors or warnings have been raised during the session lifetime.

Now, of course, this is sort of abusing the IDispose pattern, and if test code inside a using blocks throws an exception AND the validation block also throws an exception the second exception will mask the first.

Conceptually, if we have this scenario:

```
using (var managerSession = new Session(managerRole))
{
    Assert.IsTrue(managerSession.DoJob(), "Manager did not do his job");
}
```

...and the assert fails or the call to managerSession.DoJob() throws an exception, then I would like the Session Dispose() method to skip the validation block, i.e.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (NoExceptionThrown())
    {
         Assert.IsFalse(this.serviceConnection.HasErrors(), "Service connection has errors");
    }

    this.serviceConnection.Dispose();
}
```

...such that the test method never fails with 'Service connection has errors' if it actually fails with 'Manager did not do his job'

My question is: Is it at all possible to implement the 'NoExceptionThrown()' method here? Is there some global property that can be checked, or something hidden in Thread.CurrentThread that could be utilized?

Update:

My question is *not* how to refactor this :-)

I could of course use this pattern instead:

```
Session.ForRole(managerRole, (session) => { /* Test code here */ });
```

With the static method ForRole() defined like

```
public static void ForRole(Role r, Action<Session> code)
{
    var session = new Session(r);
    try 
    {
        code(session);
        Assert.IsFalse(session.serviceConnection.HasErrors());
    }
    finally 
    {
        session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I am curious whether there exists some way of grabbing the exception state as described above.

Comment: Two things. First, yes, this is abusing `IDisposable`. Use `IDisposable` to mean "I own an unmanaged resource that should be freed as soon as possible". Making it mean something else makes your code hard to read. Second, are you concerned about *any* exception, or only *uncaught* exceptions? Suppose the test code throws an exception, catches it, and completes normally. Should that be flagged?

Comment: Ah, I'm only concerned about _uncaught_ exceptions. I'll update the question...

Comment: As for abusing IDisposable: I am actually more concerned about missing the common validation for each session than the potential masking of errors, so this question is more of a 'nice to have' feature. The actual blocks of test code are 10-100 lines of UI automation code, and we have already spotted defects going undetected because one of the validation steps were missed in one of the blocks (or reported in the wrong block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been helpful if there were an overload of `IDisposable.Dispose` which took a parameter of type `Exception` to indicate what exception, if any, was pending in a `finally` context associated with its cleanup.  While a `Dispose` method generally shouldn't care about the particulars of the exception, conditions may arise during the `Dispose` method which should be reported to the caller.  Any exception thrown from `Dispose` will replace any exception that had been pending in the caller's `finally` context, so it would be helpful if a `Dispose` method could encapsulate a pending exception before replacing it.  Unfortunately, no such feature exists and I do not expect any to be added.

While there are some hacks that may be used to achieve something like the desired effect, the only semantically-correct method is for the exception to be a parameter to a `Dispose` method.  The problem with any other approach is that a `Dispose` may be run from within multiple nested `finally` blocks, some of which have pending exceptions and some of which don't; code which examines the execution context to determine the status of the most deeply nested `finally` block may fail if that block isn't the one which guards the lifetime of the object being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one sure, but ugly, way to do it is to have a bool (default false) on your class.

```
using (var managerSession = new Session(managerRole))
{
    Assert.IsTrue(managerSession.DoJob(), "Manager did not do his job");
    managerSession.NoExceptionThrown = true;
}
```

I don't think you'll get much cleaner than that with your IDisposable pattern.

In this instance, a try... catch... finally may work better as you'd have direct access to the exception object, which you can test for null-ness (is that a word?) and possibly even store it for later use. You shouldn't lose anything, because `using` is just sugar for a try catch finally.

Comment: Yes, nullness is a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: And for a more serious remark, setting a property that controls the validation block in the Dispose method is actually not that good idea. If we're adding something on every using-block anyway, then it would be better to refactor the existing validation code to a separate method and just call that before closing the scope

Comment: @Christoffer Yeah, I think you're trying to do a round-plug-into-a-square-hole thing with using. As supercat pointed out, the proper way is to pass the exception object or an indication of if an exception occurred to dispose. So, I guess you could add the appropriate method, just ditch the using and call Dispose(exception) yourself? There are issues there, as well, and I don't think you'll be able to force the language to do exactly what you'd like without gutting it and reattaching its head backwards :c. And as far as I know, there's no way to check for any exception outside a catch block.